# To check the sign and convexity of a transcendental function using naive approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, alternative-proof, boundary-value-problem

I was solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041499/a-particular-solution-to-fracd2ydx2y-csc-x) BVP:
$$y''+y= \csc(x),  y(0)=0=y(\pi/2), x\in[0,\pi/2]$$
By following the same lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2041519/500398) solution using the variation of parameters method, I got the solution:
$$y=-x\cos(x) + \sin(x)\log(\sin(x))$$
I now need to determine its **sign** and **nature** (concavity/convexity/a mix of both) in $[0,\pi/2]$.

**My approach**

1. To check the **sign** of y in $[0,\pi/2]$: Both the terms of $y$, viz. $-x\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))$ are negative and so is $y$.
2. To check the **nature** of y in $[0,\pi/2]$: On differentiating $y$ twice, I got: $$y''=x \cos(x)+\sin(x)+ \cot(x)\csc(c)-\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))$$
   Interestingly, again on investigating the signs of all the four terms of $y''$ individually, they turned out to be each positive and thus so is $y''$ implying the convexity of $y$.

**My question**

Is there a nicer way to verify the sign and especially the nature of $y$? In particular can we do it without finding the solution, directly from the given data?

**P.S.** This question was supposed to be answered in an objective question paper, in a limited time frame without using any calculators or plotters.

Answer (score 1):

If you use inspection, the first derivative cancels "close" to $\frac \pi 5$.

At this point, the value of the second derivative is
$$\frac{1}{4} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)
   \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}+\frac{\pi
   }{5}\right)-\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}\right)-1\right)$$ which is $2.52197$.

Comment: That is a helpful observation +1

Answer (score 0):

1. To check the **sign** of y in $[0,\pi/2]$: Both the terms of $y$, viz. $-x\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))$ are negative and so is $y$.
2. To check the **nature** of y in $[0,\pi/2]$: On differentiating $y$ twice, I got: $$y''=x \cos(x)+\sin(x)+ \cot(x)\csc(c)-\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))$$
   Interestingly, again on investigating the signs of all the four terms of $y''$ individually, they turned out to be each positive and thus so is $y''$ implying the convexity of $y$.
   This implies $y$ to be **negative** and **convex** in $[0,\pi/2]$

[[image: Graph of <span class=]$y$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etl6z.jpg)